# disable tracking in EF core returns tracking error

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, ef-core-2.0

I have this repository as you can see :

```
 public class TestCenterRepository:ITestCenterRepository
    {
        private readonly PetrolTestCenterDbContext _context;


        public TestCenterRepository(PetrolTestCenterDbContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;

        }
        public TestCenter GetById(Guid testCenterId)
            => _context.PetrolTestCenters.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == testCenterId && u.Deleted == false);

        public void Add(TestCenter testCenter)
        {
            _context.PetrolTestCenters.Add(testCenter);
            _context.SaveChanges();

        }
}
```

when i call my add function i get this error :

```
'The instance of entity type 'TestCenter' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'
```

So i try to disable tracking on my context as you can see :

```
public class PetrolTestCenterDbContext : DbContext
{


public PetrolTestCenterDbContext(DbContextOptions<PetrolTestCenterDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
    ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;


}
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TestCenterConfig());

}

public DbSet<TestCenter> PetrolTestCenters { get; set; }

}
```

After adding disable tracking i get the same error .

Comment: how are you calling your methods?  because if you call the `Add` method after you call `GetById` you will get this error.  you don't need to add your object back to the context, because by pulling it the first time, EF is already tracking this object by it's primary key.